# Matching different text amounts to the same sized logo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, logo, font-size

Using photoshop I have a brand logo that I need to use with different amounts of text.

for example the logo is 6 points long ......

In one project I need to have 'hello' above the logo - That's fine, it fits.

But in another project, I have to have 'hello everybody' above the 6 point logo.

I am wondering the best way to make it fit so it looks as consistent with the previous 'Hello' as possible?

I am using photoshop and have adjusted text size and have played with the horizontal/vertical scales, which I am doing by sight. Basically I've set two ruler lines on either side of 'hello' (220 pts) and am reducing 'hello everybody' (170pts) font size to fit this which obviously makes the text size smaller.

Just wondering if this is the best method to acheive whatI am trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no way to have Photoshop automate what you want.  You have to tell Photoshop what you want to do. It's only a tool. It doesn't know what looks consistent or good.  Your eyes and brain are the best judge of that.

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr. I guess worded that wrong. I guess I was asking for any tips/advice on my issue apart from using my eyes. I'll edit/update now.

Comment: drop some guides if it helps you place the text accurately.